# Rijndael encrypt file in C# and decrypt as string in Delphi

Tags: c#, delphi, encryption, aes, rijndael

I am trying to encrypt a file in C# and decrypt the content in delphi as a string. I have tried several settings, key/block sizes and modes. Currently the code on C# side is:

```
private void EncryptFile(string inputFile, string keyCode, string outputFile)
{
    try         {   
        byte[] key = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(keyCode);
        byte[] iv = new byte[16];
        Array.Copy(key, iv, 16);

        FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create);

        var RMCrypto = new AesManaged();
        RMCrypto.KeySize = 256;
        RMCrypto.BlockSize = 128;
        RMCrypto.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt,
                                           RMCrypto.CreateEncryptor(key, iv),
                                           CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open);

        int data;
        while ((data = fsIn.ReadByte()) != -1)
            cs.WriteByte((byte)data);
            
        fsIn.Close();
        cs.Close();
        fsCrypt.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
}
```

The key parameter is a C# string "1234567887654321".
And the reverse part in delphi using the DEC library looks like that:

```
    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

var
  RCipher: TCipher_Rijndael;
  FileStream: TFileStream;
  StringStream: TStringStream;
  StringBytes: TBytes;
  Key: String;

begin

  Key := '1234567887654321';

  StringBytes := TEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Key);

  RCipher := TCipher_Rijndael.Create();
  FileStream := TFileStream.Create('C:\path\to\file.txt', fmOpenRead);

  StringStream := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.ANSI);

  RCipher.Init(StringBytes[0], 32, StringBytes[0], 16);
  RCipher.Mode := cmECBx;
  RCipher.DecodeStream(FileStream, StringStream, FileStream.Size);

  Memo1.Text := StringStream.DataString;

  RCipher.Free;
  FileStream.Free;
  StringStream.Free;

end;
```

but all i get is random characters... where could be the problem? Are the algorithms incompatible with each other?

EDIT: Replaced term 'chinese characters' by 'random characters' to avoid confusion with unicode issues.

Thanks to pf1957 the solution was unexpected yet simple. I was using the Delphi Encryption Compendium  library 5.1 which was obviously not AEC compliant. After i upgraded the code to the [DEC 5.2](https://code.google.com/p/delphidec/) library all worked fine.

Comment: Have you tried `RijndaelManaged` instead of `AESManaged`?  Here's a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged.aspx).

Comment: Looks like unicode ansi mismatch

Comment: Yes, that was my first choice... But i got the same problems. Then i read that the AesManaged is compliant to the AES standard and i thought its better to go with that, as its more likely that the delphi library also implements the AES standard.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the keys are in unicode, 8 unicode characters are 16 byte = 128 bit. that should be right. the string in the file however is ANSI encoded. thats why i initalized the stringstream with ANSI.

Comment: to eliminate an encoding issue, you could convert the bytes to Base64 so that they are safe. Write those to a file, then read your base64 convert back to Bytes in Delphi and then see if it makes a difference

Comment: Delphi version please

Comment: @WarrenP its Delphi XE2

Comment: And is the C# data being encrypted in UTF8 or UTF16 before it is stored? I'm guessing UTF16?

Comment: @WarrenP the file written from c# has no encoding, its the raw bytes from the encryption stream, a binary file. but before it was a textfile with ANSI encoding, which should not matter since FileStreams just work with the raw bytes and it was never read as a string in C#, the string variables inputFile and outputFile are only the file names...

Comment: How do you get Chinese characters from an ANSI encoded buffer?

Comment: @thalm: Is **C:\path\to\file.txt** correct name for you encrypted output? I do not see a reason, why it should not work. I've tested your code using VS10+SP1 and .NET 4 against Delphi XE3+SP1 using DEC 5.2 (with minor fix in ModuleUnload signature) and it works for me

Comment: @David I do not understand the phrase 'chinese chars' literally but as a metaphore to completely unreadible text

Comment: @pj1957 If you take English text, encoded as ANSI, and interpret as UTF16, you see chinese characters.

Comment: @David: Encoded English text is still US-ASCII even encoded as ANSI. StringStream encoding is defined as ANSI, so I'd expect the assignment DataString (ANSI) to Memo1.Text should perform automatic conversion to Unicode, isn't it?

Comment: Another reason it may not work is the padding. If your plain text is not exactly a multiple of the block size, the encryption will pad the plain text to the first multiple. If your decryption routine (what is TCipher_Rijndael?) assumes another type of padding decryption will fail also.

Comment: @pf1957 thats great news! i am using DEC 5.1, maybe thats a problem. good point... i have VS2010 and Delphi XE2, so it should work...

Comment: @all sorry for the misleading term 'chinese characters', as pf1957 pointed out, that was a metaphor for unreadable text and signs.

Comment: @pf1957 that was it! my DEC 5.1 was buggy... i found the DEC 5.2 and it worked perfectly... wow. will update my post. you can write your comment as answer and i will accept it. thanks for the hint!

Comment: @thalm: thanx, everybody who will need it can find answer in your edited question and me, I'm not a collector ;)

Comment: @thalm Glad you sorted it. You did confuse me with the reference to Chinese though!  ;-)

Answer (score -1):

You are using 16 byte (128-bit) key data, while you are setting encryptor/decryptor to use 256-bit key.

So, after you'll fix the usage of TStringStream (*never* use it with binary data), check code or documentation for both libraries to know what is done with key data - most likely it is not used directly as key but used as 'password' for key derivation process.

Comment: Rijndael is defined for fixed blocks 128 bits and key long 128, 192 and 256 bits. He declared and passed 256-bit key: 16 unicode chars = 32 bytes * 8 bits. There is no special 'password' processing by default, passed key is just copied. As I commented above, his code works for me (on text file to avoid your issue concerning TStringStream)

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I'm missed that string converted to key using unicode.